# Thumbnail preview not showing on mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I upgraded to Catalina, thumbnail preview stopped working on my desktop.
I tried everything that I know, "Show icon preview" is ticked, Preview app is applied to open all kinds of images, but still just the generic icons appears. This is very frustrating, since I am working with images and video files, that I need quick access to.
Hope to someone help me with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to resolve the preview issue by doing following.

1. In Finder, press `Shift ⇧ + Command ⌘ + G` and enter ~/Library/Preferences.
2. Then find com.apple.finder.plist and move it to the Trash.
3. Right-click on the Finder icon in the dock and select Relaunch.

- Press and hold the Option Key
- Right-Click or Control-Click Finder in your Dock (maintain holding Option)
- Select Relaunch from the pop-up menu (If you don’t see it make sure you hold Option before right-clicking Finder)

If this doesn't work, ensure that JPG files are associated with Preview. To do this, right-click on one of them and choose Get Info. Under the Open With section, select Preview, and then click Change All. You may need to relaunch Finder with this method too.

Comment: I had this issue in MacOS Monterey, and your solution worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: On Catalina that also worked